# Its only displays one Hotel reservation

Tags: c

I'm doing a hotel reservation so i'm trying to display the reservation using the iD that the user inserted but I can't get it the program just freezes with no error or anything i tried many things and looked online could not find the answer. i tried doing an while inside the if loop it also did not work cant figur out where the problem is.
Thanks.

```c
void display(char *a)
{
    FILE *fp;
    rec = count;
    int choice;
    fp = fopen(a ,"r");
    struct  hotelStruct *temp = (struct hotelStruct *)malloc(sizeof(struct hotelStruct));
    temp->first_name = (char *)malloc(10* sizeof(char));
    temp->last_name = (char *)malloc(15*sizeof(char));
    temp->passport = (char *)malloc(15*sizeof(char));
    temp->nationality = (char *)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    temp->room = (char *)malloc(10*sizeof(char));
    temp->email = (char *)malloc(30*sizeof(char));
    if (fp == NULL)
        printf("Error!!");
    printf("\nEnter your Reservations iD:\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    fseek(fp, 0, 0);

    while (rec)
    {


        if (choice == temp->id) {
            fread(&temp->id, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
            printf("\niD: %d\n", temp->id);

            fread(temp->first_name, 10, 1, fp);
            printf("First Name: %s\n", temp->first_name);

            fread(temp->last_name, 15, 1, fp);
            printf("Last name: %s\n", temp->last_name);

            fread(temp->passport, 15, 1, fp);
            printf("Passport: %s\n", temp->passport);

            fread(temp->nationality, 30, 1, fp);
            printf("Nationality: %s\n", temp->nationality);

            fread(temp->room, 10, 1, fp);
            printf("Room: %s\n", temp->room);

            fread(&temp->bed, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
            printf("Beds: %d\n", temp->bed);

            fread(temp->email, 30, 1, fp);
            printf("Email: %s\n", temp->email);

            fread(&temp->phone_number, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
            printf("Phone number: %d\n\n\n", temp->phone_number);
        }
        rec--;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    free(temp);
    free(temp->first_name);
    free(temp->last_name);
    free(temp->passport);
    free(temp->room);
    free(temp->email);
    free(temp->nationality);
}
```

Comment: Be sure to read about [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your count and rec is undefined and as they were not initialised.

Do read Id first before comparing it.

```
 fread(&temp->id, sizeof(int), 1, fp); 
  printf("\niD: %d\n", temp->id);
  if (choice == temp->id) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for the unorganized code

Answer (score 0):

At the start of your function, you initialize `rec = count` - but at that point `count` is undefined (as far as can be determined, because you haven't provided the full code - are they both global variables?).

In addition, you're reading from stdin for some parts, but from an open file descriptor (`fp`) for others - but there's no association between them.

Please rethink your example and update the post - the structure is confusing and salient details are missing.

Comment: I'm really sorry for the unorganized code I did the thing is I cant copy the whole code (or can I) idk its my second time in this page but the guy above answered it